# Is there a mythological creature that is an hybrid of dragon and a griffin?

Tags: creature-design, mythical-creatures, dragons

Like... A cockatrice with four legs and maybe horns. Is there an actual mythological creature like this, big enough to humans to ride on, or will I have to make one up? (For plot reasons, it is better if I get something already existing...) The closest I could get to it was an opinicus, but it doesn't entirely satisfy the needs. Ideas?

Comment: Will [hippogriff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippogriff) do instead?

Comment: I assume your thinking of western dragons right ?

Comment: Yes, western dragons.

Comment: from google i found dracogriff "Dracogriffs are hybrids of griffins and dragons. They tend to have a similar color pool to dragons, scales on their backsides, horns, spines, dragon-like tails, with feathers on the ends, wings that switch from feathers to skin halfway down, and draconic bird talons (meaning they look mostly like bird talons, but are shaped similarly to dragon claws)."

Comment: but i cant found the myth relate to it or image about it outside of fanmade so iam not sure is this actually fanmade or real myth creature

Comment: Oh, thanks. That's interesting... But I have the feeling that that is not an  "official" myth creature, since google didn't show any relevant results. I found examples of them on fur afinity, tho. I migth use one of those for the looks... But the name...I will have to see. Thanks.

Comment: XD. I only saw your second comment now. Sorry. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Isn't this more suited to [mythology.se]?

Comment: A funny observation - an unspoken rule of the internet, not too dissimilar from Rule 34, is one that says "If it exists, there is a dragon version of it".

Comment: Heh heh. Right now I'm flashing on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_Movie in which there was a running gag that anything could interbreed with anything. Except humans, they were yucky.

Comment: Large flying not-quite-lizard not-quite-bird creature? I gotcha bro: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pterosaur

Answer (score 6):

**MANTICORE**

The [Manticore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manticore) is a Persian mythical beast with the head of a human, mane and body of a lion, and a tail that is sometimes illustrated as spined like a porcupine's, sometimes like a scorpion's tail. It is often depicted with large bat wings, and usually with three or four rows of teeth in its mouth. Its name means 'man-eater', and it is generally not considered a nice being.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Quetzalcoatl**

[image]**

Originally the name of a particular shapeshifing Aztec god with bird (griffin) and serpent (dragon) features. He was not the only "feathered serpent" in American mythology though.

In modern reimaginings of mythology "Quetzlcoatl" and "feathered serpent" often refers to this type of creature. The same way "Pegasus" refers to any flying horse, even though it was originally the given name of a particular flying horse. For example in D&D This sort of creature is called a "Coatl".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A snallygaster is a creature that is often depicted as winged quadruped with a mixture of avian and reptilian qualities, which may be what you are looking for. They are also described as picking people up and flying away with them, which would fulfill the requirement of being rideable by humans